# Why can't I use the boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

so, I'm really new to bender and I'm trying to make a ring for myself. but for this I have to remove part of the skull, but when I try to use the boolean difference modifier it simply doesn't change anything. But it doesn't act like it didn't work.[image]

I want to cut the Cylinder from the sckull
[image]

[Link to file Download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/jocj14cw9vjgcbe/ring.blend/file)

Comment: you have 3 objects, so what is supposed to be booleaned?

Comment: I want to cut the cylinder from the skull, as I said, pretty new don't know the proper language yet hehehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology of your skull is bad, there are vertices overlaying and inner faces, f you select some external vertices in *Edit* mode then press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them and see what happens inside you will see it by yourself. Boolean doesn't work with overlaying vertices and inner faces, and I don't know if there's a quick way to fix the problem as there are a lot of vertices.

[image]